# Calculate Laplace transform of the product of $t$ and $f(t)$ by differentiating $f(t)$ (5.5-8)

Tags: derivatives, proof-verification, laplace-transform

**Request**:

Please check my work. State where errors, if any, occurred and how to correct them. Is there a better way to calculate the transform other than the present method given?

**Given**:

Find the Laplace transform $\mathcal{L}\{t\cdot e^{-t}\cdot \cos(t)\}$ by carefully selecting and differentiating $f(t)$.

**Solution**:

$$\mathcal{L}\{t\cdot f(t)\}=-F'(s)$$

$$f(t)=e^{-t}\cdot \cos(t)$$

$$F(s)=\frac{1+s}{(s+1)^2+1}$$

$$F'(s)=\frac{(-1)\cdot(2s+2)(1+s)}{[(s+1)^2+1]^2}$$

$$F'(s)=-\frac{2(s^2+2s+1)}{[(s+1)^2+1]^2}$$

**Answer**:

$$\mathcal{L}\{t\cdot e^{-t}\cdot \cos(t)\}=\frac{2(s^2+2s+1)}{[(s+1)^2+1]^2}$$

Comment: Your third line should be $$\frac{1+s}{(s+1)^2+1}$$

Comment: I keep making these dumb little mistakes. Thank you for catching it.

Comment: You can check them at www.wolframalpha.com. [here](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Laplacetransform%5Bt+e%5E%7B-t%7Dcos%5Bt%5D%2Ct%2Cs%5D&x=0&y=0) you can see the syntax for the problem.

Comment: The numerator should be $s^2+2s$